# What is the regex to find a number followed by a period and replace the period

Tags: regex, replace, pspad

I am using PSPad and I am trying to replace the first period followed by a space with a pipe so I can use the pipe as a delimiter.

My data has lots of periods so I only want to replace the first one.  The data looks like:

```
1. Wallbaum, H., S. Krank, 
3. Levinson, H.S., Highways, people,
4. Mercier, J., Equity, social justice, 
225. Lemp, J.D., et al., 
17. Chi, G. and B. Stone,
```

Since the data always starts with a number followed by a period & space I figured the simplest thing to do was look for the number and space.

I have figured out the 'Find' part of the regex as `^\d+\.` but how do I replace the period & space but leave the number?

Comment: Find `^(\d+)\.` and replace by `$1`

Comment: Here's the [live demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/tZ9eY4/1)

Comment: Awesome!  If you want me to vote, make it an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capturing group as follow

```
^(\d+)\.\s
```

and replace it with the first captured group `$1` which will be the number.

[**Regex Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/tZ9eY4/1)

1. `^`: Starts with
2. `(\d+)`: Matches one or more digits and adds this in the first captured group
3. `\.`: Matches dot literally, need to escape as it has special meaning in regex
4. `\s` or (space): Matches one space. `\s` will also match any space characters like tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Pspad supports look-behind or not but if it does then you can also use:

```
\d+\K\.
```

and replace it simply with `|`.

See [Demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/uA0iZ2/1)

`\K` is a look-behind and is used in making the match, but it is not included in the output.